# postgres 10 - convert categorical column to presence absence matrix

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to create a new table like so:

original table:

```
site_id, site_period
1,       period_a
2,       period_b
2,       period_c
3,       period_d
4,       period_a
4,       period_b
```

desired table:

```
site_id, period_a, period_b, period_c, period_d
1,       1,        0,        0,        0
2,       0,        1,        1,        0
3,       0,        0,        0,        1
4,       1,        1,        0,        0
```

This is probably a duplicate question as this is a relatively simple problem, but I didn't know what vocabulary to use to describe it to find a solution. I'm familiar with coding logic, but not terribly comfortable with sql queries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT` and conditional aggregation.

```
CREATE TABLE desiredtable
AS
SELECT site_id,
       count(CASE site_period
               WHEN 'period_a' THEN
                 1
             END) period_a,
       ...
       count(CASE site_period
               WHEN 'period_d' THEN
                 1
             END) period_d
       FROM originaltable
       GROUP BY site_id;
```

Comment: Hi thanks, this solution worked after some fiddling with commas and semicolons and such. One thing, how would I do this if I didn't want to use the count() function? in many cases, there are multiples of period_a for site_id = 1 in the table because multiple sources reported that site_id = 1 belonged to period a. in the output matrix from the code above, if 3 sources reported site_id = 1 belongs to period_a the resulting value is 3, and I'd just like it to be 1