# PostGIS conditional aggregration - presence/absence matrix

Tags: postgresql, matrix, conditional-statements, postgis, aggregation

I have a dataset that resembles the following:

```
site_id, species
1,       spp1
2,       spp1
2,       spp2
2,       spp3
3,       spp2
3,       spp3
4,       spp1
4,       spp2
```

I want to create a table like this:

```
site_id, spp1,    spp2,    spp3,     spp4
1,       1,        0,        0,        0
2,       1,        1,        1,        0
3,       0,        1,        1,        0
4,       1,        1,        0,        0
```

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372659/postgres-10-convert-categorical-column-to-presence-absence-matrix), however the issue I face is that my list of species is significantly greater and so creating a massive query listing each species manually would take a significant amount of time. I would therefore like a solution that does not require this and could instead read from the existing species list.

In addition, when playing with that query, the count() function would keep adding so I would end up with values greater than 1 where multiples of the same species were present in a site_id. Ideally I want a binary 1 or 0 output.